# How can I apply a Interface to a HTTP response

Tags: angular, typescript

In my app I get a response from an API which has a response with the following pattern.

```
export interface IApiResponseBody<T = any> {
    Error?: string;
    Message?: string;
    RowsAffected?: number;
    Success?: boolean;
    Data?: T;
    RowCount?: number;
}
```

and I have no issue assigning the interface to the response which then lets me access the elements in response. Where I am having an issue is when I try to assign a interface to the `Data` via `T` like

```
let myData: IApiResponseBody<IPerson>  = {
    Success: true,
    Error: "",
    Message: "",
    RowsAffected: 9,
    Data: [{name: 'Steve', age: 26, gender : 'male'},
            {name: 'Susan', age: 21, gender : 'female'},
            {name: 'SteveFrank', age: 29, gender : 'male'}]}
```

I get an error no matter if I use an array in `Data` or a simple Doc.

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: index.ts:9:5 - error TS2559:
>   Type '{ name: string; age: number; gender: string; }[]' has no
>   properties in common with type 'IPerson'.
>
> 9     Data: [{name: 'Steve', age: 26, gender : 'male'},
>         ~~~~

So how can I apply an interface to my `Data` element no matter if it's an array of docs or a simple doc.

Here is a link to the above code on Repl.it

[Sample Playground](https://repl.it/@NoSoup4you2/Array-To-Object)

Comment: Maybe a simple mistake? Your data (`myData.Data`) is an array, but your interface is a plain type. Shouldn't the interface definition include `Data?: T[]` (ie. an array of T instead of just T)? Or perhaps `myData` should be `IApiResponseBody<IPerson[]>`?

Comment: On a side note I would strongly recommend against adding `success:true, error` etc or anything indicating a failure. Use the standard http codes and then extend *that* response body with error information. If your api succeeded return 200 with the required http message body. This way you create a more pure restful api.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
export interface IApiResponseBody<T = any> {
    Error?: string;
    Message?: string;
    RowsAffected?: number;
    Success?: boolean;
    [key: string]?: T | T[];
    RowCount?: number;
}
```

and:

```
let myData: IApiResponseBody<IPerson>  = {
    Success: true,
    Error: "",
    Message: "",
    RowsAffected: 9,
    Data: [{name: 'Steve', age: 26, gender : 'male'}] // or {name: 'Steve', age: 26, gender : 'male'}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, you want to access a data that might not exist. Because Data?: `T[]`, is a shorthand of Data: `T[]` | undefined. It means that Data may contain a value of `T[]` or it may contain the value undefined.

So, when you call, myData.data[0].name it means, it may have the value `steve` or you want to call name property of first object of undefined data which is totally not acceptable, so the error trowed.

**Solution 1:**

you can check if the data is exist first, then print the object or property of object.

```
if (myData.Data) {
  console.log(myData.Data[0].name)
}
```

**Solution 2**

Or you can say there must be data, remove the `?` character from interface.

```
export interface IApiResponseBody<T = any> {
  Error?: string;
  Message?: string;
  RowsAffected?: number;
  Success?: boolean;
  Data: T[];
  RowCount?: number;
}
```

Live solution: [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@RafeeMuhammad/Array-To-Object)

Comment: Thats what i tried but it does not let me access the elements then in data like this console.log(myData.Data[0].name)

Comment: it seems both t myData: IApiResponseBody<IPerson[]> and Data?: T[]; will achive the same thing when i print console.log(myData.Data) i get [ { name: 'Steve', age: 26, gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Susan', age: 21, gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'SteveFrank', age: 29, gender: 'male' } ] but i cant access any element or myData.Data.length

Comment: may be the problem lies in your response. I have tried in my project, works nicely. if you don't get response by console.log(myData.Data[0].name), it is your response problem. because typescript restrict the response, but can't prevent to come.

Comment: If you look at https://repl.it/@NoSoup4you2/Array-To-Object it does not work with the code. so not sure why. This code uses a static response emulating what it would expect from http server

Comment: Can you explain to me the logic why i have to check before i can access the data ? if (myData.Data) {
    console.log(myData.Data.length)
}

Answer (score 0):

`Data?` has to be an Array of type T, or if you want to allow an Array or a single Object, use a union.

```
export interface IApiResponseBody<T = any> {
  Error?: string;
  Message?: string;
  RowsAffected?: number;
  Success?: boolean;
  Data?: T | T[];
  RowCount?: number;
}

export interface IPerson {
  name?: string;
  gender?: string;
  age?: number;
}
```

Which now allows you to do:

```
let myData: IApiResponseBody<IPerson> = {
  Success: true,
  Error: "",
  Message: "",
  RowsAffected: 9,
  Data: [
    {name: 'Steve', age: 26, gender: 'male'},
    {name: 'Susan', age: 21, gender: 'female'},
    {name: 'SteveFrank', age: 29, gender: 'male'}
  ]
}
```

or:

```
let myData: IApiResponseBody<IPerson> = {
  Success: true,
  Error: "",
  Message: "",
  RowsAffected: 9,
  Data: {name: 'Steve', age: 26, gender: 'male'}
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle Array and or Doc in Data ? My API will have an Array when there is more then one Doc in the response, if it is only one Doc then its not an Array. If not i guess i will have to build 2 Interfaces and then apply based on the API expected return

Comment: Ok, tried your solution and i get the following error  TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
index.ts:16:13 - error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'IPerson | IPerson[]' has no index signature. I updated the Playground with your code https://repl.it/@NoSoup4you2/Array-To-Object